# Use of unresolved identifier 'SKStoreReviewController' but imported StoreKit already

Tags: ios, swift, storekit, skstorereviewcontroller

I've already imported StoreKit into the ViewController where I want users to trigger the actions so that they can rate my app, however I keep getting the below error despite the number of times I've cleaned and built my app etc. so I think its likely something I did wrong

This is my code:

```
    func promptUserToRateApp() {

     if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
        SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
     } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
     }
   }
```

and this is the error im getting:
[image]

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? What's your Base SDK?

Comment: v 8.2.1 for xcode and IOS v10.2, oh is it because I need to update to 10.3?

Comment: Im guessing theres no way to test this unless I try to download IOS 10.3 etc. etc.?

Comment: Yep, you need Xcode 8.3.x or Xcode 9 so you can have a Base SDK of 10.3 or later.

Comment: I am using Xcode 9.4.1. Still I have the same issue.

Comment: @soorejbabu Have you correctly imported `StoreKit`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because I'm on Xcode 8.2.1 and IOS 10.2 where SKStoreReviewController is not available.

For a quick way to install and switch Xcode versions, refer to the below link:

https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/314-installing-and-switching-xcode-versions-from-the-command-line

Comment: Do you know which is the earliest Xcode version that supports `SKStoreReviewController`?

Answer (score 4):

you need to write `import StoreKit`

[image]

Comment: Sorry, if it wasnt clear, I already wrote that I imported StoreKit as can be seen in my title, thanks

Comment: can you share Xcode file as I am not getting such error and check are you using latest Version n Xcode